# regex to match with a delimiter with grep in linux

Tags: regex, linux, grep

I am working with the following kind of strings

```
DANT_NN-LT-OS-NET-S1-NOTIFIC_263947473_                 _?TEST1
```

I need to get all the first section of the string before the "?".

I'm testing this on linux, this string is coming from a DB and I am processing it from a ksh.

I am running the following from the ksh script.

`echo $sql | grep -Eo "[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+[ ]+[_]"`

This is the last one, I have tried a lot of options.

The thing is, at the end I just receive either only the first part

```
DANT_NN-LT-OS-NET-S1-NOTIFIC_263947473_
```

Or everything ...

Any help with this regex is greatly appreciated.

Comment: cannot reproduce. You might have non-ascii characters between `3_` and `_?`. Can you run `echo $sql | od -bc` and see what it comes back with?

Comment: oh, well, yes, actually in the middle there are some tabs ..
`
 _  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t  \t
0000660 040 040 040 040 040 040 040 137 077 116 131 103 055 114 124 105
                                      _   ?`

Comment: then try `echo $sql | grep -Eo "[a-zA-Z0-9_\-]+[[:space:]]+[_]"`

Comment: @1_CR : Thanks, fixed with 2 things ... adding ::space:: , not sure why it is not simply recognizing the space +, and changing the IFS for "
" (enter) , it was not getting the rest of the characters because of that.

Comment: "Everything up to the question mark" is simply `(.*)\?` See http://regex101.com/r/jA8lI8 for a demo. If you need to split a string at the ? you might use `cut -d'?' -f1`. I don't think 'grep' is the best tool for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following regex

```
^[^?]+
```

[regex101 demo](http://regex101.com/r/yG5cU3)

```
echo $sql | grep -oE '^[^?]+'
```